# Very low mic volume on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa, hdmi, microphone

I have tried answers suggested in the earlier similar question and as I am just starting with Ubuntu after a long time , I hope some one will be able to help me

There is very very low mic volume on google / Skype
Here are the things, I tried

1. Alsa mixer volume ajust HDA intel HDMI is 0 and not able to change HD
   intel Pch is what I made to maximum.
2. Increasing the volume via volume setting - Doesn't help

Output of `aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20751/2 Analog [CX20751/2 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install and launch   **gnome-alsamixer** , go to the second tab HDA INTEL PCH,
increase all "mic" , "mic boost",  "internal" and "capture"  faders level,
also verify faders "mute" state.

Comment: I had downgraded to ubuntu 12.04 in some time constraint. Will re upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 LTS and let you know , if this does solve my problem . Sorry about that

Comment: I verified this today after upgrading to 14.04 LTS . Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just verified by using google chat and mic sound still seems distorted. it is bad at the receiver end though it became better after increasing mic volume like @laugeo suggested

Comment: Ok, you can monitor  your own micro sound running in a terminal `vlc pulse://`  (install vlc eventually)  : using a headphone and speaking , set a correct mic level using the various faders in gnome-alsamixer (try also standards fader in "sound setting" "input" tab  )